# docker server hang when multiprocess is called and give this error <class 'OSError'>

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, multiprocessing

I am using mutiprocess to call the api paralley. the server is running in docker, it get hanged when multiprocess is called.

Getting this error:
Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://10.195.30.80:8780' after 20 s: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://10.195.30.80:8780' after 20 s: connect() didn't sh in time <class 'OSError'>

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./data_app
  ports:
    - 8000:80
  volumes:
    - ./data_app/code:/usr/app/code
    - /data/dev/dc:/usr/app/code/dc
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:3.6.2


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx uwsgi

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/default

WORKDIR /usr/app/code

CMD ["/bin/bash", "start.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
```

please help me below are my code:

```
def call_1(params):
    return fun_1.gather_inputs(**params)


def Call_2(params):
    return fun_2(**params)



def multiprocess(**inputs):
    start_time = time.time()
    if inputs['service'] == ['metal']:
        with Pool(1) as pool:
            # result1 = pool.apply_async(call_1, [inputs])
            result2 = pool.apply_async(call_2, [inputs])
            val1, val2 = {}, result2.get()
            val1[inputs['required_info']]={}
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
    else:
        with Pool(2) as pool:
            result1 = pool.apply_async(call_1, [inputs])
            result2 = pool.apply_async(call_2, [inputs])
            val1, val2 = result1.get(), result2.get()
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

Comment: Well, it looks like ``call_1`` (which you are not calling on bare-metal) tries to open a TCP connection and fails. That has everything to do with the call, container and network setup (which you do not show), and nothing with multiprocessing (which you do show). Please [edit] your question to include the details of the actual problem. Consider also whether your problem is more appropriate for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: hi MisterMiyagi thanks for the response, added docker detail

Comment: i have commented that part in bare-metal, how it will be called?